# Android Studio slow since macOS update

Tags: android, performance, android-studio, lag, macos-catalina

Since I updated my Macbook 2016 Touch Bar to Catalina 10.15.6, android studio seems to perform quite slow and laggy. Even scrolling is starting to lag pretty hard.
I already set up my laptop again and deleted everything that was on it. but still nothing got better.
Idk what to do, because coding like that gets pretty annoying.

Does anyone know a solution to this?

Answer (score 8):

Follow these steps:

Step 1:

Go to Android -> Preferences

Click on Build, Execution, Deployment

Click on -> Compiler

Check the Option — Compile independent modules in parallel (may require larger heap size)
Check on Use in-process build” and “Configuration on demand and click OK button
Restart Android Studio and that’s it.

Step 2:Update your android studio vm options file

Find your Android Studio app launcher file

Right click the icon -> Select “Show Package” Contents”

Go to Contents -> Bin folder

Open “studio.vmoptions” file using text editor

Add/change the following lines in your file and save it.

Old Options

-Xms256m

-Xmx1280m

-XX:MaxPermSize=700m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240m

Newly Updated Options (You can even increase more based on your Mac or PC’s RAM speed)

-Xms512m

-Xmx2560m

-XX:MaxPermSize=700m

-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=480m

Step 3: Restart or start the Android Studio

Step 4: In case if the Android Studio doesn’t open, which means you’re old vm option file got cached somewhere.
Follow these simple commands in your command line and remove the old file.

> cd ~/Library
> cd Preferences
> cd AndroidStudio3.1 (This should be your current Android Studio version )
> rm studio.vmoptions

Comment: Step 2 did it for me. Thanks!